# How to achieve click event via dependency property in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml

I'm fairly new to the world of Silverlight so please bear with me. I have created a custom pivot item control to be displayed in a pivot control. Now in this custom control there's a button. Now i could just add the click event handler to the button in the custom control's backing cs file and that would be ok. But is there a way for me to specify the event handler of the custom control's button during the declaration of the custom control? i.e. something like this in my pivot_page.xaml

```
<custom:myPivotItem background="..." height=".." width=".." click="myHandler"/>
```

where myHandler is declared in pivot_page.cs? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by declaring a **RoutedEventHandler** in the custom controls cs file (myCustomPivotItem.cs).

```
 public event RoutedEventHandler Click;
```

Then in onApplyTemplate I get access to the rectangle object with

```
 Rectangle rect = this.GetTemplateChild("rectObject") as Rectangle;
 rect.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(RectView_Tap);
```

I then declared RectView_Tap in the same cs file (myCustomPivotItem.cs)

```
    private void RectView_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Click != null)
            Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
    }
```

in my MainPage.xaml i declared the custom control like so

```
 <controls:PivotItem x:Name="pivotitem2">
     <view:myCustomePivotItem x:Name="custompivotItem2" Click="myHandler"/>
 </controls:PivotItem>
```

and in MainPage.cs i declared myHandler...

```
 void myHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //delegate operation
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
    }
```

And it works as expected!! :) Hope it helps anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You could expose a public event on your custom control that maps to the button's click event.

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Click
{
    add { this.button.Click += value; }
    remove { this.button.Click -= value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for a button, I tried applying it to a rectangle's Tap event which is a EventHandler<GestureEventArgs> type and it doesn't work. I even added a dependency property for it but i get an exception. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cool Dude - you should be able to use the same approach, but your event would have to also be defined as the EventHandler<GestureEventArgs> type:  `public event EventHandler<GestureEventArgs> Tap { add { ... } remove { ... } }`

Comment: Now I'm getting a null pointer exception because the rectangle object is being referenced in the public event property before the onApplyTemplate() is called.

Comment: @Cool Dude - I'm not sure about that.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627410/how-to-access-a-named-element-in-a-control-that-inherits-from-a-templated-contro); perhaps you're having the same problem.

Comment: @@Dr. Sadly that doesn't help either. Thanks

Comment: Solved it by using RoutedEvents from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721611.aspx#id0430049