# How to trigger a method in a XAML element when a textproperty changes

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, event-handling

I really don't know how to search to find a solution to this (I googled a lot, maybe I'm blind...).

I have a ComboBox which also contains a TextBox. The ComboBox is instantiated in a separate Control.xaml with a specific DataContext, where it gets its content for the Popup list.
Now when I type something into the TextBox, I want to trigger a method which then filters the list of my DataContext for the specific elements.
So my ComboBox.cs has some of the following content:

```
    public event EventHandler FilterTextChanged;

    protected virtual void OnFilterTextChanged(EventArgs args)
    {
      FilterTextChanged?.Invoke(FilterText, args);
    }

    public string FilterText
    {
      get { return _filterText; }
      set
      {
        //This point is reached when I type something into the TextBox within the ComboBox
        if (_filterText == value) return;
        _filterText = value;
        OnFilterTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        OnPropertyChanged("FilterText");
      }
    }
```

And in my Control.xaml, I have configured it like this:

```
<my:ComboBox x:Name="FURecipeComboBox"
             AuthorizationMode="IsEnabled"
             IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
             StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
             FilterTextChanged="FURecipeComboBox_OnFilterTextChanged"
             ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeFileNames}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Value, Delay=100, ElementName=AlphaNumericTouchpadTextVarIn}"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type adapter:ToolRecipeVariableInfo}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}">
</my:ComboBox>
```

But I just can't get it to catch the event "FilterTextChanged", and my method "FURecipeComboBox_OnFilterTextChanged" will not be reached anytime...
I would be really really glad for some hints or help!

Kind regards
BB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at RoutedEvents at [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview)

This is a example post from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846195/how-to-achieve-click-event-via-dependency-property-in-silverlight)

In your case try to change EventHandler to RoutedEventHandler.

I made a small example:

Main.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="348,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" MyClick="UserControl1_MyClick"/>

</Grid>
```

Main.cs

```
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_MyClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yep");
        }
    }
}
```

control.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public event RoutedEventHandler MyClick;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (MyClick != null)
                MyClick(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

control.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="372.313" d:DesignWidth="350">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="218" Margin="59,54,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown"/>

</Grid>
```